# SVG how to draw <image> to exact pixel size

Tags: image, svg

The SVG `<image>` element is required to have width and height attributes.
The image is shrinked/stretched to fit these dimensions.

However, it's not always possible to know the dimension of the image in advance. For example a PNG file might be uploaded by a user.

I would like produce SVG that draws the image to it's natural pixel dimensions - without being shrinked/stretched, and without having to inquire the dimensions of the image in advance. I do not care if the image will cover some other part of the SVG.

Is this possible?